# How to go to webpage and check a html checkbox

Tags: scripting, web

At the coffee place I use to go, the captive portal grants wifi access after you check a checkbox in their landing page (accepting the TOS). That wouldn't be an issue if I didn't spend hours there and they didn't asked every 15 min or 100 MB again and again.

Could I automatize the process of connecting with Bash, Perl, Python or any other resource commonly found on Ubuntu?

Html snipped of it:

```
<form action="http://1.1.1.1/reg.php" method="post" name="form2">
<input name="url" value="2EB8F3587D88E953591ABBE4833943D6C1241D2842D3D2FC83D98ED1D0613DC1BFFB8380" type="hidden">
      <center>
        <p><img src="logo_main.jpg" align="absmiddle" height="125" width="134"> 
        </p>
        <p> 
          <input name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="checkbox" type="hidden">
          <input checked="checked" name="checkbox2" value="checkbox" onchange="evalue(this);" type="checkbox">
          <font face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif">I accept the <a href="http://1.1.1.1/tos.htm" target="_top">Terms and Conditions</a></font> 
        </p>
        <p>
          <input name="Submit" value="Enter" id="button1" type="submit">
      </p></center>
</form>
```

Comment: Is that value inside `URL` always different?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the `url` value here is some sort of session key unlike what the field name implies. You could try to get it using e.g. `sed`:

```
wget -qO- http://… | sed -n 's/<input name="url" value="\([^"]\+\)" type="hidden">/\1/p'
```

Then using this you could build a request on your own using `curl`. It might help to get inside Chrome developer tools where you can right-click on the request to get a copy of it as a `curl` command line.

Alternatively, you could use Selenium. Using Selenium for Python the code would then look like:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('checkbox2').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('button1').click()
```